# Why does my Python program give run time error on Kattis interpreter on Babelfish?

Tags: python, dictionary, input

When I submit this file to Kattis I get a `Run Time Error` with no further explanation. It seems like simple enough code, but maybe I'm just missing something.

It runs on my python 3 interpreter. Why does it not work on Kattis? (or maybe other interpreter)

Problem: https://open.kattis.com/problems/babelfish

```
dictionary = dict()
userInput = input()
while userInput != "":
    buf = userInput.split()

    english = buf[0]
    foreign = buf[1]

    dictionary[foreign] = english
    userInput = input()


userInput = input()
while userInput != "":
    if userInput in dictionary:
        print(dictionary.get(userInput))
    else:
        print("eh")

    userInput = input()
```

Comment: Your program is taking input infinite times. You should stop when you get EOF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the input data is not obtained with the input() function as you're doing. You should read the standard input, like so:

```
for i in sys.stdin:
    ab = i.split()
    a = int(ab[0])
    b = int(ab[1])
    # Solve the test case and output the answer
```

[Kattis documentation on Python3](https://open.kattis.com/help/python3)

Comment: Would this be without the int conversion? As there are not supposed to be any integer variables; it's organized by a dictionary.

Comment: oh yeah, i haven't actually run your code, just checked the documentation that you have to read the sys.stdin variable. Probably you would just iterate i and use it as your values.

Comment: That isn't working for me either; on the python3 Linux compiler I am using the input() function and it takes in standard input just fine; it's only the Kattis one that doesn't.

Comment: This is helpful, clean and works, but it's not the only way as indicated. You can in fact use `input()` as long as you [catch the `EOFError`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62290582/6243352). Note that this version with `stdin` doesn't trim the lines while the `input()` version does, so this affects the `if userInput != ""` condition in OP's code. The empty line would be `"\n"` with `stdin`.

Answer (score 1):

Kattis recommends the `sys.stdin` to read the input data. However it is completely fine to use `input()` as well.

The breaking condition for the second `while` loop isn't working in your code.

While there is an empty string telling you the first block is ending, there isn't one for the 2nd block.

After the last data from the stream is caught by input(), you are still trying to get more data with `userInput = input()` in the next loop.
Thus throwing an `EOFError`, which you may catch to get a breaking condition:

```
while True:
    try:
        userInput = input()
    except EOFError:
        break
```